# Is there evidence whether SpaceX is making a profit launching rockets?

Tags: spacex, commercial

Since SpaceX is privately held, I'm not able to find information about whether they are actually turning a profit on their launches of reusable rockets. (Perhaps they are conducting launches, but at a loss.) Is there any publicly available information about that?

Comment: One thought: Many (most?) of their launches are Starlink launches, which means they are their own customer. So even if you had access to all their accounting, it would be hard to know how profitable the external-facing launch business would be without the economies of scale that come from so many Starlink launches.

Comment: They could have positive cash flow on a per-launch basis, but still not have paid off all the development costs. Accounting can be fairly difficult, particularly without any actual data.

Answer (score 12):

I doubt very much that you will be able to find any significant details about SpaceX profitability beyond the occasional vague or "aspirational" tweet from Musk. As you have pointed out SpaceX is a private company. It does not have shares that can be traded on the stock exchange nor is it required to publish financial reports like public companies are.

To make the problem harder their business model is large and variegated with vast incomes and expenditures. These including the whole Starlink enterprise which may or may not run at a large small or no profit at some time, commercial satellite launches, private ventures like Dear Moon, NASA contracts for Starship, HLS, ISS resupply and crew rotation. All helped along by the hundred million or so that Musk put in initially, the contribution of the other private shareholders and bank loans.

You can argue round in circles whether SpaceX is profitable or not based on all of that. But SpaceX is not a traditional company, unlike most companies whose entire reason for existence is to make a profit, SpaceX was created for Elon Musk's purposes and marches to the beat of a different drum. Money is vitally important to SpaceX, but only as a means to an end not as an end in itself so SpaceX doesn't have to make a profit.

But beyond that, is the reuse of Falcon 9 profitable? I would be utterly shocked if Falcon 9 flights were not highly profitable. We don't know for sure, but not throwing tens of millions of dollars of precision engineering into the Atlantic Ocean after each launch is a vast saving compared to what must surely be modest recovery and refurbishment costs. Some boosters have flown more than ten times and I believe there have been more than one hundred booster re-flights in total. In recent years SpaceX has captured the majority of the space launch market, they're not stupid.

It could be argued that NASA was unable to refurbish the Shuttle economically so why should SpaceX? But the NASA's approach although technically effective was financially ridiculous.

Two tiles applied per worker per week?
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Space_Shuttle_thermal_protection_system#Slow_tile_application

This is how SpaceX apply their tiles:
https://www.reddit.com/r/SpaceXLounge/comments/m4ii51/video_of_spacex_installing_starship_heat_shield/

Will the first Starship or two crash and burn, yes they will. But they will learn from those experiences and fix whatever failed. They might spend longer but even at one tile an hour it would be more than an order of magnitude faster than NASA and although I’m not normally a betting man I’d wager they will find something that takes them no more than a few minutes/tile.

Comment: I'd say that the best evidence for SpaceX's profitabilithy regarding Falcon 9 is that they are substantially undercutting the prices of competitors,  even though they have an overwhelmingly large share of the market for space launch and at this point have no need to offer their services below cost.  Falcon 9 has also now proven itself to be among the most reliable launchers in history, so there should no longer be a risk premium causing SpaceX to offer cheap flights.

Comment: It's a good answer. As a non-engineer, resusability sounds like a good idea to me as well. But there is surely work involved in checking the rockets before launch. Reusability didn't work out so well in the shuttle program. I guess that uncertainty is what's behind my question.

Comment: There is a lot of work and expense involved in recovery and refurbishment, but fishing for rockets worth ten million plus dollars a pop has got to be worth it surely? There is a vast difference between how SpaceX runs the Starship program and the way that NASA administered the Shuttle program. Look at the thermal protection tiles:  
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Space_Shuttle_thermal_protection_system#Slow_tile_application
2 tiles applied/worker/week! Now look at how SpaceX are doing it:
https://www.reddit.com/r/SpaceXLounge/comments/m4ii51/video_of_spacex_installing_starship_heat_shield/

Comment: I've expanded on that in the body of the answer for future reference

Comment: The Shuttle was advertised as a way to reduce launch costs, but political interests turned it into a way to direct lucrative contracts to supporters in industry early in its development and NASA never had an incentive to actually reduce costs. Things like fully reusable liquid boosters were never developed because maintaining solid booster contracts was part of the Shuttle's reason for existence. That the same political interests keep repurposing Shuttle technologies into extremely expensive, fully expendable launch systems (Ares I and V, and now SLS) further illustrates this.

Comment: NASA was unable to refurbish the Shuttle economically... because it was launched in Florida, controlled in Houston, and built on the other side of the Rocky Mountains and therefore with seals that can and did fail. (couldn't fit thought the train tunnels in one piece). AKA, bureaucracy.

Comment: When the government stopped *not* caring how much it cost to win the race, because of that *one* thing *we* did to 'win', it was downhill. We've been riding our own coattail into the ground for the last 53 years after putting a man on the moon.

Comment: @Slarty Saying that Space X is not profit driven is a stretch. Musk might claim otherwise, but he is not a majority owner anyway.

Comment: @DanHanson It's a bit debatable wether they are significantly undercutting competitors yet (outside of government launches). Soyuz can be cheaper, and an Ariane 6 is just a few million more (while also being more capable - in theory -) The market is still supply driven so they have no incentive to lower their prices yet.

Comment: @Antzi Musk's Trust has voting control over 78.3% of the outstanding stock of SpaceX so its more or less whatever he wants. Musk is driven to see his dreams realised, he is not driven to have a big bank account - money is vitally important, but only as a means to and end not as an end to itself. Musk took insane levels of financial risk to make SpaceX what it is today. As it turns out it paid off, but he knew he stood a very good chance of losing all of his money. https://fcc.report/IBFS/SAT-MOD-20200417-00037/2274435.pdf

Answer (score 5):

The Wall Street Journal published a [story](https://www.wsj.com/tech/behind-the-curtain-of-elon-musks-secretive-spacex-revenue-growth-and-rising-costs-2c828e2b?mod=Searchresults_pos1&page=1) about this very question. It's behind a paywall, but here are the pertinent figures:

> The privately held company generated $55 million in profit on \$1.5
> billion in revenue during the first quarter of 2023, according to
> results in documents viewed by The Wall Street Journal.

> Before SpaceX’s small quarterly profit at the start of this year, the
> company reported about \$5.2 billion in total expenses for 2022, up
> from \$3.3 billion the year earlier, the documents show. Revenue
> doubled to \$4.6 billion, helping the company reduce its loss last year
> to \$559 million from $968 million.

So... not a lot of profit, anyway.

(I guess my question asked about the reusable launches specifically, but the sources of the income and expenses aren't disaggregated in the article.)

Comment: I saw that article too. I was sad that the starship/super heavy development costs weren't broken out. I was also surprised that they lost money for a couple of recent years.

Comment: @OrganicMarble apart from what they're spending on Starship (which we know to be more than the HLS contract is worth), they built and launched 4000+ satellites starting in 2019, developing multiple new generations of Starlink satellites and user terminals in the same period, and only started to see significant revenue from Starlink relatively recently. I'm a little surprised they're making a profit overall...maybe they're bound by Falcon 9 launch rate, and *can't* just spend that money on more Starlink sats.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, according to **The Wall Street Journal**, SpaceX made a profit of $55\ million$ on $1.5\ billion$ in revenue during the first quarter of 2023 ². This is a significant improvement from the previous two years, where the company had reported losses ². The report also suggests that SpaceX's financials offer a clue into how the company is faring while it ramps up Starlink and races to get the Starship rocket flying ¹.

Adapted from a conversation with Bing, 8/23/2023

(1) Elon Musk’s SpaceX turns profit after two years of losses: report. https://www.msn.com/en-us/money/markets/elon-musk-s-spacex-turns-profit-after-two-years-of-losses-report/ar-AA1fpAsN.

(2) SpaceX reportedly turned a profit in the first quarter. https://www.msn.com/en-us/money/markets/spacex-reportedly-turned-a-profit-in-the-first-quarter/ar-AA1fpvWs.

(3) Rocket Lab's Future is More Than Just Rockets. https://www.msn.com/en-us/money/companies/rocket-labs-future-is-more-than-just-rockets/ar-AA1fvIox .

(4) Revisiting SpaceX’s $36\ Billion$  Valuation After Its First... - Forbes. https://www.forbes.com/sites/greatspeculations/2020/06/02/revisiting-spacexs-36-billion-valuation-after-its-first-manned-mission/ .

(5) SpaceX revenue: $2 billion from rockets last year, Jefferies ... - CNBC. https://www.cnbc.com/2019/05/20/spacex-revenue-2-billion-from-rockets-last-year-jefferies-estimate.html.

Comment: "Adapted from a conversation with Bing, 8/23/2023"  I approve of this disclaimer and support this kind of light use of genAI.  I'm not sure what the AI policy says about this though.